# Approach for using session scoped bean in SOAP based web service

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, soap

I am developing Spring-MVC application.

I am using Session scoped bean to store user related information, which is used by many spring service bean.

I have requirement of exposing SOAP based web service with login on every request.
As session scoped user bean is required internally, do I need to create user bean on every user soap request? and invalidate the session to destroy created user bean at the end of request.

Please suggest better approach.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the impact / hinderance to change the scope of user bean from session to request ? as it seems the web service need to cater user on per request basis only.

Comment: Changing session to request will require much code change.

Comment: could you please elaborate on changes you envisage ?

Comment: As user bean is used across application to retrieve user info for displaying as well as for storing in database. If I think of making user bean as request scope then I will have to load user related data on every request from database. Consider 4 database queries to fill user bean.

Comment: Okies. In this case IMO you should create two spring beans for user bean with different id, one session scoped while other request. Inject / use them accordingly in your application w/o any session management of your own.

Comment: How do I inject both the bean at same place. Consider one method is called from web user which is using session bean and same method called from soap service at that time I need to use request scope bean.

Comment: You need to create an additional bean for the bean to which user bean is injected. e.g. `beanA` will have `userBeanSession` and `beanB` will `userBeanRequest`. Here `beanA` and `beanB` corresponds to same class / controller which you invoke either from web user or from soap service. Let know if you need me to elaborate further.

Comment: Yes please elaborate.. How will I inject beanA and beanB in my controller/service.

Comment: First define the user beans for session and request scope as `<bean id="userBeanSession" class="x.y.z.UserBean" scope="session" />` and `<bean id="userBeanRequest" class="x.y.z.UserBean" scope="request" />`. Then create two beans for the Controller / Service with respective user bean injected as followed `<bean id="beanA" class="a.b.c.SomeServiceOrController">
 <property name="userBean" ref="userBeanSession"/>
</bean>` and `<bean id="beanB" class="a.b.c.SomeServiceOrController">
 <property name="userBean" ref="userBeanRequest"/>
</bean>`

Comment: Thanks for the help. But with your approach, I will have to create 2*number of services, as one which injects userBeanSession and other which injects userBeanRequest. In this way I will have to make two different paths of code flow, one with session and one with request. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As explained in example you only create additional beans for same class. (Given that there are no specific scope related logic in code)